# Cómo centrar el título de un conjunto de opciones de un Spinner en Android Studio?

Tags: android

tengo una duda. Les muestro la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría que el título de "Artículos" este colocado más en el centro. Cómo se puede realizar esto con XML? es posible hacerlo desde JAVA?

Les dejo el código de mi Activity (Java):

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cargas_descargas);

spinner_tercer_tupla_xml = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_art);

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_tandas,datos);
    spinner_tercer_tupla_xml.setAdapter(adaptador);

    spinner_tercer_tupla_xml.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            switch (i) {

                case 0:


                    Toast to_bidones = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ha seleccionado Bidones", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    to_bidones.show();
                    break;

                case 1:


                    Toast to_dispenser_plastico = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ha seleccionado Dispenser Plástico", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    to_dispenser_plastico.show();
                    break;

                case 2:


                    Toast to_canillas = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ha seleccionado Canillas", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    to_canillas.show();
                    break;

                case 3:


                    Toast to_dispenser_electrico = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ha seleccionado Dispenser Eléctrico", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    to_dispenser_electrico.show();
                    break;


            }


        }


        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

} //Fin del OnCreate

Código del content_main de XML:

```
android:id="@+id/nueva_cd"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".cargas_descargas"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_cargas_descargas">



<ScrollView

    android:id="@+id/scrl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_vertical_cuarta_tupla"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">



    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">





    <LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/layout_horizontal_primer_tupla"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="#00b0ff">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tandas"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="bottom|center"
                android:text="Tanda N°:"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_horizontal_segunda_tupla"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?attr/colorControlHighlight"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">


            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/articulos"
                android:layout_width="155dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Artículos"
                android:textSize="15sp" />


            <ImageView

                android:id="@+id/img_carga"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_carga" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cargas"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:text="Carga"
                android:textSize="15sp" />


            <ImageView

                android:id="@+id/img_descarga"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_descarga" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/descargas"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Descarga"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

        </LinearLayout>







    <LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/layout_vertical_tercer_tupla"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">




            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_horizontal_tercera_tupla"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <ImageButton

                    android:id="@+id/add_art"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_new_art" />

                <Spinner

                    android:id="@+id/sp_art"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:prompt="@string/title_spinner"
                    android:spinnerMode="dialog">

                </Spinner>


                <EditText

                    android:id="@+id/edtx_carga"
                    android:layout_width="95dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="Cantidad"
                    android:inputType="number"/>

                <EditText

                    android:id="@+id/edtx_descarga"
                    android:layout_width="95dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="Cantidad"
                    android:inputType="number" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/layout_horizontal_cuarta_tupla"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?attr/colorControlHighlight"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <ImageView

                android:id="@+id/img_money"
                android:layout_width="165dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_money" />

            <EditText

                android:id="@+id/edtx_carga_money"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="$"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

            <EditText

                android:id="@+id/edtx_descarga_money"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="$"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

        </LinearLayout>





    </LinearLayout> <!-- Fin del "layout_vertical" -->

    </LinearLayout> <!-- Fin del "layout_vertical_cuarta_tupla" -->

</ScrollView>
```

De mi res-string:

Prueba_de_Modulos
    Settings
      
    Herramientas
    Guardar Cambios
    Cancelar Tanda
    Finalizar tandas del día
    Artículos

Comment: Agrega como estas constuyendo el Spinner, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: Ya añadí el código!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En realidad lo que deseas es cambiar el texto definido en

```
android:prompt
```

esto no es posible para un `Spinner` usando la clase del Android SDK.

---

Una solución puede ser crear un `Spinner` personalizado. revisa el [ejemplo de Tarum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694786/how-to-customize-a-spinner-in-android3):

Cree un adaptador personalizado con un diseño personalizado para su `Spinner`.

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.pioedittxt5);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.travelreasons, R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

R.layout.simple_spinner_item

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="@style/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="@style/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

En los estilos agregue sus dimensiones y altura personalizadas según su requisito.

```
 <style name="spinnerItemStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">

  </style>

  <style name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle" parent="android:TextAppearance.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">

  </style>
```